# CPU % utilization - Get detail of the percentage

Tags: sql-server-2012, cpu, pressure

We have sometimes CPU issues on one of our production server (DynamicAx database on an alwaysOn primary server). People are asking us to give them the detail of that CPU %  used. Here is an example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywdvm.png)

Ok there are no issue right now but sometimes CPU % goes up to 90%. We are asked to explain the detail of that 90%!!! They want to see a list of processes (spid) with a percentage for each and by adding all those percentages they will have the 90% CPU utilization.
Process_1 -- 8%
Process_2 -- 10%
Process_3 -- 50%
Process_4 -- 2%
Process_5 -- 20%

TOTAL – 90%

Ok so it’s process_5 the problem, let’s go kill it… (joke)…

Is there a magic query, a magic tool that can provide this kind of list?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You can see a list of processes under the CPU tab in Resource Monitor.

If you want more advanced details you can use [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) for activity summaries or even logging. Maybe you can give that summary to the "people."